# choosing the correct matrix to solve this optimization problem - Pseudoinverse

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, pseudoinverse

While searching for the uses of the pseudoinverse i stambled across this problem:[image]

**The way i approached it**

$u_i = f_i \Delta t + u_{i-1}=  x_i\Delta t + u_{i-1}$ and $s_i = 0.5 x_i \Delta t^2 + s_{i-1}$ where $u_i$ is the velocity at $t_i$ and $s_i$ is the position.

So: $u_{10} = \Delta t\sum_{1}^{10} x_i $ and  $s_{10} = 0.5\Delta t^2\sum_{1}^{10} x_i $

**The problem with that** is that if i write matrix A it is the following matrix:

$$ A_{2x10} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.5Δt^2 & 0.5Δt^2& ... & 0.5Δt^2 \\ Δt & Δt &... &Δt  \end{bmatrix}  $$

So that $$Ax = y$$

**matrix A is not full rank** ($rank(A)=1$), so $(AA^T)_{2x2}$ is **not invertible**. I need A to be full rank, so $AA^T$ is invertible. That way i can find the least norm solution with this formula:

$$x = A^T ( AA^T)^{-1} y$$.

**How should i write A?** (any hint is appreciated)

*I repeat the problem for clarity:*

We have a unit mass at rest at $t=0s$. We apply forces $x_i$ for $i-1<t\leq i,$ for $i =\ 1,2,...,10$

If $y_1$ is the position of the unit mass at $t=10s$, and $y_2$ is the velocity of the mass at $t=10s$ then i want to find the least norm solution of $\vec{x} = [x_1,x_2,...,x_10]^T$ that transfers the unit mass at $y = [y_1,y_2]^T$.

Comment: In the first place, what even is a fat matrix?

Comment: it means that if $A$ is $nxm$ then m>n. It has more columns that rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are not correct. We have the following dynamical equations for the system

$$\begin{bmatrix}\dot{p}\\\dot{v}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}p\\v\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}x(t)$$

where $p$ denotes the position and $v$ the speed, hence, $\dot{p}=v$. The general solution under zero initial conditions is given by

$$\begin{bmatrix}p(t)\\v(t)\end{bmatrix}=\int_0^t\begin{bmatrix}t-s\\1\end{bmatrix}x(s)ds.$$

Assuming that the $x$ is piecewise constant and changes values at times $t_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,N$, we obtain that

$$\begin{bmatrix}p(t_N)\\v(t_N)\end{bmatrix}=\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}\begin{bmatrix}t_N-s\\ 1\end{bmatrix}ds\right)x_i.$$

Now, we have that

$$
\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}\begin{bmatrix}t-s\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{-(t_N-t_i)^2}{2}+\dfrac{(t_N-t_{i-1})^2}{2}\\
t_i-t_{i-1}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}t_n(t_i-t_{i-1})+\dfrac{1}{2}(t_{i-1}^2-t_i^2)\\
t_i-t_{i-1}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

When $t_i=i$, then this reduces to

$$
\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}\begin{bmatrix}t-s\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
N+\dfrac{-2i+1}{2}\\
1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

As a result,

$$\begin{bmatrix}p(t_N)\\v(t_N)\end{bmatrix}=\sum_{i=1}^N\begin{bmatrix}
N+\dfrac{-2i+1}{2}\\
1
\end{bmatrix}x_i.$$

So, the matrix $A$ is given by

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{19}{2} & \dfrac{17}{2} & \dfrac{15}{2} & \ldots & \dfrac{1}{2}\\
1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

and we have that $y=Ax$. This matrix $A$ is full rank and, as such, the matrix $AA^T$ is invertible.

You should be able to continue from there.